# PHP add pair in array during loop without overwriting the existing key

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this loop:

```
    $lines = array();
    $line = 0;
    $line_text = '';
    $line_tot_len = 0;
    $iTweetText = 0;
    foreach ($tweet_text as &$text) {
        $text_len = strlen($text);  //space

        if ($text_len <= 22 && ($line_tot_len + $text_len) <= 22) {
            $line_text .= $text . ' ';
            $line_tot_len = strlen($line_text);
            $lines[$line] = $line_text;
        } elseif ($text_len > 22) {                
            $line_text = '';
            $line_tot_len = 0;
            $line_text .= $text . ' ';
            $line_tot_len = strlen($line_text);
            $lines[$line + 1] = mb_substr($text, 0, 22) . '-';
            $tweet_text[$iTweetText + 1] = mb_substr($text, 22, $text_len);
            $line++;
        }elseif ($line_tot_len + $text_len > 22) {
            $line_text = '';
            $line_tot_len = 0;
            $line_text .= $text . ' ';
            $line_tot_len = strlen($line_text);
            $lines[$line + 1] = $line_text;
            $line++;
        }
        $iTweetText++;
    }
```

Here `$tweet_text[$iTweetText + 1] = mb_substr($text, 22, $text_len);` I am adding a new pair key value to the array in the position where I need it (next loop).
The problem is that in this way I am overwriting the existing key at that index, instead I want to add 1 pair and move all the next ones incrementing by 1.

How can achieve this?

Thank you bery much.

Comment: Who and why you voted -1?

Comment: Why do not increase the line with 2 instead `$line++;`, so you wont overwrite it.

Comment: And you do not increase the `$line` at your first case.

Comment: @lolka_bolka that's not what I need. I need to append a pair to the array $tweet_text without overwriting the existing keys

Comment: Anyway, can you show us for example 10-15 lines to test, and the expected result_

Answer (score 0):

Because my answer to the comment is too long, i add it as an answer:

But you overwrite. This is your problem. How do you do not want to overwrite, if you overwrite? :) Here is a condition:

```
if ($text_len <= 22 && ($line_tot_len + $text_len) <= 22) {`
```

if 2 rows after each other match with this criteria, first will be overwritten with second, becuase in this case you do not incrase the `$line`.

The other case:

```
} elseif ($text_len > 22) {
```

At here you add a new key:

```
$lines[$line + 1] = mb_substr($text, 0, 22) . '-';
```

then incrase the `$line` with `$line++`. So, if your current `$line` is 7, then you add a line with key 8, set the line to 8, so if the first case will hapen, it will also overwritten.

**Others**

In your post you says,

> I am adding a new pair key value

No, you are adding simple values (strings) to your array.

Comment: The problems is with $tweet_text[$iTweetText + 1] = mb_substr($text, 22, $text_len); not with the lines array. I need to add a new value with a specific key number to the next loop, without overwriting the existing key (if it exists)

Comment: So why don't you check, is that key exists? `while (array_key_exists($line)) { $line++ }`. So you increas $line until you get a non existent array key.

Comment: Becuase I need that value to be in that specific key. So if I need it to be in the key 3, but key 3 already exists, then key 3 should become 4.

Comment: I think your whole concept is bad. You want to achive something, what you can not. Please show us some example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way:

```
    $lines = array();
    $line = 0;
    $line_text = '';
    $line_tot_len = 0;
    $iTweetText = 0;
    foreach ($tweet_text as &$text) {
        $text_len = strlen($text);

        if ($text_len <= 22 && ($line_tot_len + $text_len) <= 22) { 
            $line_text .= $text . ' ';
            $line_tot_len = strlen($line_text);
            $lines[$line] = $line_text;
        } elseif ($text_len > 22) {                
            $line_text = '';
            $line_tot_len = 0;
            $line_text .= $text . ' ';
            $line_tot_len = strlen($line_text);
            $lines[$line + 1] = mb_substr($text, 0, 22) . '-';
            $tweet_text[$iTweetText + 1] = mb_substr($text, 22, $text_len) . ' ' . $tweet_text[$iTweetText + 1];
            $line++;
        }elseif ($line_tot_len + $text_len > 22) {
            $line_text = '';
            $line_tot_len = 0;
            $line_text .= $text . ' ';
            $line_tot_len = strlen($line_text);
            $lines[$line + 1] = $line_text;
            $line++;
        }
        $iTweetText++;
    }

    $last_line_height = 50;
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $last_line_height = $last_line_height + 50;
        $image->draw()
                ->text($line, new Imagine\Imagick\Font(new \Imagick, $font_path, 39, $image->palette()->color($tweet_text_color)), new Imagine\Image\Point(70, $last_line_height));
    }
    $image->save($img_save_path);
    break;
```